# Eclipse: Problems View: Warnings: Eclipse Not Seeing JSTL libraries

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl, warnings

I'm using Eclipse 3.72 on Windows 7, with a legacy webapp.

In "Problems View" I am getting a lot of warnings about JSTL tags being unknown, like this one:

```
Unknown tag (c:if)
```

Everything in the webapp compiles and runs beautifully.

I have the JSTL jars in my  war/WEB-INF/lib

I have these tags in my header.jsp:

```
<%@ page language = "java" session = "true" import = "java.util.*, java.text.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

I'm including my header.jsp in my other JSPs like this

```
<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>
```

I'm guessing Eclipse thinks those tags are unknown, because they are only in the header.jsp which is included at the top of the other JSPs.

Is there anyway to get rid of those "unknown tag warnings" without shutting off the JSP warnings?

I have these jars in my_webapp/war/WEB-INF/lib dir:

```
jstl-api-1.2-rev-1.jar
jstl-impl-1.2.jar
```

Those two files also appear in Eclipse at myproject > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries

Comment: jta(Java Transaction API) has nothing to do with jstl (JavaServer Pages Tag Library), but of course this is not the cause of your problem.

Comment: Try to use this one http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar - only one jar instead of two separate (only this without api and impl in separate jars)

Comment: What is your include statement - I mean how you include header.jsp can you paste this code into your question also?

Comment: Updated my original post

Comment: Hmmm... just for the test can you add those namespaces <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "f" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> directly in some jsp where you use it? If then the warning will be gone it means that something with the include is wrong (good path?) otherwise it means that jars are wrong or not 'visible'. But I guess they are if you don't have warning for header.jsp. I assumed that finally you use jstl-1.2.jar.

Comment: Since yesterday I changed another unrelated eclipse warning ( not using the variable JRE_LIB instead using Java_system ) that forced a rebuild.  Now these errors, now only 3, are limited to my footer.jsp. I did your experiment with the footer.jsp, saved the files, did the Run > Build All in eclipse.  Eclipse did not update and those warnings are still there.

Comment: Refresh on the whole project, and full clean doesn't help also (Project->Clean...)?

Comment: How do I refresh on the whole project in eclipse ( new to eclipse, use an independent ANT file to build my project )?

Comment: To refresh just click F5 on the project (or Right mouse button -> Refresh) on the project also. and try the clean as I wrote. However if you have warnings only there, then assuming that footer.jsp is proper it seems that everything is configured good :)

Comment: Thanks. Doing a clean and refresh removed a boat load of other warnings, but those 3 for the footer.jsp are still there, which I can live with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your jstl jars to the project's classpath in eclipse.

Look here (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to choose the right jar set according to your configuration.

Comment: I went to my project > properties > Java Build Path > libraries.
My jstl jars were already there.  What am I not seeing/doing?

Comment: hmmm... what jars you have in the classpath exactly (you can add the list to the question)

Answer (score 0):

To me this has happens only the very first time i download a project (with all needed dependencies), the solution is to refresh the project